# Структура классов

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую. Недавно начал свой путь изучения C++.

Во многих программах видел такую структуру классов:

```
car::salon::steeringWheel::rotation(180)
```

Как это вообще реализуют?

Получается, что класс car наследует все методы класса salon и steerWheel?

Как это вообще работает?

Объясните, пожалуйста)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что кто-то тут что-то "наследует"? Откуда вообще взялось упоминание наследования?

Comment: @AnT, это лишь мои догадки того, как это реализовано. Я не имею никакого представления о том, как сделать такую структуру из классов

Comment: @AnT вроде как человек с первых строк дал понять, что имеет мало опыта.  А для новичка это реально выглядит немного запутанно.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Из того, что "человек имеет мало опыта" совсем не следует, что человек будет делать непредсказуемые рандомные предположения. Человек упомянул "наследование". Это упоминание - следствие некоей цепочки выводов, которые человек сделал у себя в голове. Вот я и задаю конкретный вопрос - "что это за цепочка выводов?". Это не риторический вопрос. Это прямой конкретный вопрос

Comment: @AnT ну да, согласен, мне тоже изначально показалось, что следовало бы перед тем как задавать вопрос - заглянуть в примеры, но посмотрев на уровень репутации решил дать ответ.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, да я бы глянул, но даже не знал, в какую сторону копать) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постараюсь в кратце: есть такая штука в с++ - `namespace`. Она позваляет объявлять, определять и использовать функции с одинаковым названием и сигнатурой если они в разных наймспэйсах. Они могут быть вложенными и выглядеть примерно так:

```
namespace alfa {
  namespace beta {
    int fun();
  };
  int fun();
};

...

alfa::fun();
alfa::beta::fun();
```

Это две разные функции. При этом имена классов (с которых наверно и следовало начать) и перечисления (enum) могут использоваться подобным образом:

```
class alfa {
   enum class type{one, two};
   class beta {
     static beta *instance();
   };
};

... 

alfa::type::one;
alfa::beta::instance();
```

Тобишь, как видите, наследованием тут и не пахнет - просто вложенность.